# RxJS: Locked horizontal or vertical mouse dragging

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, reactive-programming, rxjs

I want to build an interface where you can drag in various directions with a mode selected after a certain distance. For instance if you drag 25px horizontally it locks to that mode and stays there until you release the mouse. If you drag vertically it would do the same. Other actions could happen if you click or press and hold for a long time.

Here's simplified fiddle illustrating my goal: https://jsfiddle.net/ud37p0y2/2/

It seems reactive programming would be perfect for this but i can't seem to figure out how to start these modes and then stick to them until you release the mouse. My starting point has been the many drag and drop examples but i can't seem to take it further..

Some code (TypeScript):

```
var mouseDown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($element[0], 'mousedown').select((event: MouseEvent): IPoint => {
    event.preventDefault();
    return { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
});
var mouseUp   = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($element[0], 'mouseup');
var mouseMove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($element[0], 'mousemove');
var mouseDrag = mouseDown.selectMany((mouseDownPos: IPoint) => {
    return mouseMove.select((event: MouseEvent) => {
        return {
            x: event.clientX - mouseDownPos.x,
            y: event.clientY - mouseDownPos.y
        };
    }).takeUntil(mouseUp);
});

var horizontalDrag = mouseDrag.filter((pos: IPoint) => {
    return pos.x < -25 || pos.x > 25;
});
// How would i continue from here?

horizontalDrag.subscribe((pos: IPoint) => {
    console.log('drag'); // This fires all the time, i'd like to do it once when the mode starts and then something else to be called every time the mouse has moved
});
```

From here i'd like to get an observable for horizontal drag, vertical drag, and hold events. After a mode has started the other ones should be disabled so for instance a drag wouldn't trigger long press events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a combination of `amb` + `skipWhile`.

- `amb` will give you the behavior of locking in the state,
- `skipWhile` will prevent the event from firing until they pass the threshold 
  a period of time.

The core logic will look something like this:

```
//Waits for either X or Y to emit then only propagates that one
return Rx.Observable.amb(
    mouseMove
    .pluck('clientX')
    //Wait until the threshold is reached
    .skipWhile(function (x) {
        return Math.abs(startAt.clientX - x) < 25;
    })
    //Transform the outgoing event
    .map(function (x) {
        return {
            prop: 'clientX',
            delta: x - startAt.clientX
        };
    }),

    mouseMove
    .pluck('clientY')
    .skipWhile(function (y) {
        return Math.abs(startAt.clientY - y) < 25;
    })
    .map(function (y) {
        return {
            prop: 'clientY',
            delta: y - startAt.clientY
        };
    }),
    //If neither propagates for a second, then subscribe to this instead
    mouseMove
    .startWith(startAt)
    .delaySubscription(1000)
    .tap(function (e) {
         box.className = 'press';
         prop = 'timeStamp';
         box.innerHTML = '';
    })
    .map(function (e) {
         return {
            prop: 'timeStamp',
            delta: e.timeStamp - startAt.timeStamp
         };
    }))
    .takeUntil(mouseUp);
```

**EDIT 1**

Replaced `timeout` by moving the continuation Observable into the `amb` and using `delaySubscription` instead.

And here is the fully modified version of your code:

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box');

var mouseDown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(box, 'mousedown');

var mouseUp = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.body, 'mouseup');

var mouseMove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(box, 'mousemove')
.tap(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });

mouseDown.flatMapLatest(function (start) {

    var startAt = start;
    
    box.className = 'waiting';
    box.innerHTML = 'waiting...';

    return Rx.Observable.amb(
        mouseMove
        .pluck('clientX')
        .skipWhile(function (x) {
            return Math.abs(startAt.clientX - x) < 25;
        })
        .map(function (x) {
            return {
                prop: 'clientX',
                delta: x - startAt.clientX
            };
        }),
    
        mouseMove
        .pluck('clientY')
        .skipWhile(function (y) {
            return Math.abs(startAt.clientY - y) < 25;
        })
        .map(function (y) {
            return {
                prop: 'clientY',
                delta: y - startAt.clientY
            };
        }),
        mouseMove
        .startWith(startAt)
        .delaySubscription(1000)
        .tap(function (e) {
          box.className = 'press';
          prop = 'timeStamp';
          box.innerHTML = '';
        }).map(function (e) {         
          return {
           prop: 'timeStamp',
           delta: e.timeStamp - startAt.timeStamp
          };
        }))
        .takeUntil(mouseUp);
})
.subscribe(function (x) {
    box.innerHTML = x.prop + ': ' + x.delta;
});


mouseUp.subscribe(function() {
    box.className = '';
    box.innerHTML = '';
});
```

```css
body {
    font: 12px sans-serif;
}
#box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: 0.2s background-color;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#box.waiting {
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: move;
}
#box.dragX {
    background-color: red;
    cursor: ew-resize;
}
#box.dragY {
    background-color: green;
    cursor: ns-resize;
}
#box.press {
    background-color: yellow;
    cursor: progress;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.5.3/rx.all.js"></script>
<ol>
    <li>Drag horizontally</li>
    <li>Release</li>
    <li>Drag vertically</li>
    <li>Relase</li>
    <li>Press and hold</li>
</ol>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive answer! Amb was the one i was looking for, missed it due to the strange naming. All makes sense now in retrospect though. One more thing though: what if i wanted to tap to fire a single time when either drag has started (and repeated on consecutive drags)? This would be used to prepare for the drags (the CSS class in the demo)

Comment: I also noticed that dragging but then stopping but not releasing caused the long press to trigger again. I fixed this by wrapping the drag handlers in an amb, added the timeout on this and wrapped both of those in another amb.

Comment: That's really probably better asked as another question. As to your second point, you're right, I updated my answer accordingly, basically you can move the `timeout` into the `amb` instead that way only one of the cases will end up firing.